# why i cant change value of textbox in asp wizard by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, input

i have asp wizard in my code.in the one step i have textbox.when i fill textbox i can go other step.when i am in step two,i want when click on Step Previous Button(go step one).i want add to textbox space charackter.this code not

```js
$('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').click(function () {
        
     $('input#uxInsertTitle').val(' ');

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    


    <title></title>
    <link href="Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="wizard/css/gsdk-base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Css/font/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
    
      
    </style>

</head>
<body dir="rtl" style="font-family: WebYekan !important;">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <%--  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pp" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>--%>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="wizard-container">
                                <%--  CssClass="card wizard-card ct-wizard-orange"--%>
                                <%--ActiveStepIndex="0" --%>
                                <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" DisplaySideBar="false" CssClass="card wizard-card ct-wizard-orange vr" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" runat="server" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
                                    <StartNextButtonStyle CssClass="StandardButton StartNextButton" />
                                    <StepNavigationTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Previous" ID="StepPreviousButton"></asp:Button>
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="StepNextButton_Click" Text="Next" ID="StepNextButton"></asp:Button>
                                    </StepNavigationTemplate>
                                    <WizardSteps>
                                        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep0" Title="عنوان پیشنهاد" EnableTheming="true">
                                            <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManager1" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                                                <AjaxSettings>
                                                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="uxSimilarSuggestion1">
                                                        <UpdatedControls>
                                                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="uxSimilarSuggestion1" />
                                                        </UpdatedControls>
                                                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                                                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="uxSimilarSuggestion2">
                                                        <UpdatedControls>
                                                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="uxSimilarSuggestion2" />
                                                        </UpdatedControls>
                                                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                                                    <%-- <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="uxRelatedOrganizationComponentOfSuggestionPanel">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="uxRelatedOrganizationComponentOfSuggestionPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>--%>
                                                </AjaxSettings>
                                            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                                        
                                            <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel2" Direction="RightToLeft"
                                                HorizontalAlign="Center" Transparency="35">
                                                <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: gray; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity:50); vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: none; z-index: 10000;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table align="center" style="opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity:50); background-color: #585858; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border: 1px black solid; padding: 5px; position: fixed; top: 100px; right: 50%;"
                                                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <span style="color: White; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma;">لطفا چند لحظه صبر كنيد...</span>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="uxLoading" ImageUrl="~/UserControl/Admin/Image/loading.gif" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
                                            <table style="margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 10px; line-height: 34px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="Td1" style="width: 110px;">نام :


                                                

                                                    </td>
                                                 
                                                </tr>



                                            


                                              

                                                <tr>
                                                  
                                                    <td class="Td2">
                                                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxSimilarSuggestion1">
                                                         
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="uxInsertTitle" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="420px" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'
                                                                autocomplete="off" onkeyup="textCounter();" Style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px" onkeydown="textCounter();"
                                                                CssClass="StandardFont SuggestionTitle" onfocus="show()" onblur="hide()" OnTextChanged="uxInsertTitle_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="HideForm();"></asp:TextBox>


                                                         
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </td>


                                                </tr>


                                                <tr>

                                                    <td class="Td1"></td>

                                                    <td class="Td2">

                                                        <asp:Button ID="searchreg" runat="server" Width="203px" CssClass="btn " BackColor="#2a77ba" ForeColor="White" OnClientClick=" return false;" Text="جستجوی معمولی"></asp:Button>

                                                     
                                                    </td>



                                                </tr>

                                             
                                            </table>


                                        </asp:WizardStep>
                                        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="شرح ">
                                            <div id="stepthreee" style="margin: 10px 15px; text-align: center; width: 91%; padding: 5px; background-color: rgb(232,232,232); font-size: 12px; border-radius: 6px;">

                                            
                                           <asp:Label ID="titlesteptwo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <%--//Start Add Sbr 1395-05-18 --%>
                                            <table style="margin: 20px auto; width: 95%;">
                                               </table>

                                                  </asp:WizardStep>



</body>
<script src="wizard/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wizard/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--   plugins   -->
<script src="wizard/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
   


    //Add End Doc

   
   

  

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#uxInsertTitle").bind("change", EnableNextButton);

        $("input#uxInsertTitle").bind("change", checkBoxChecked);
        DisableEnableButton();
        DisableEnableButtonCp();
       

        var button = jQuery(".StartNextButton")
     

        $('#Wizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton').addClass('btn btn-primary');
        $('#Wizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton').val('مرحله بعد');
        $('#Wizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton').css('float', 'left !important');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton').addClass('btn btn-primary btnLeft');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton').val('مرحله بعد');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').addClass('btn btn-danger');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').val('مرحله قبل');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').addClass('btn btn-success');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').val('اطلاعات وارد شده مورد تایید می باشد- ارسال');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishPreviousButton').addClass('btn btn-danger');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishPreviousButton').val('مرحله قبل');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton').css('float', 'left !important');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton').css('margin', '5px');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').css('float', 'right !important');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').css('width', '130px');
        $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').css('margin', '5px');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').css('float', 'right !important');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').css('margin-right', '360px');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').css('width', '250px');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishButton').css('margin-bottom', '-40px');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishPreviousButton').css('float', 'right !important');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishPreviousButton').css('margin', '12px');
        $('#Wizard1_FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID_FinishPreviousButton').css('width', '130px');




    });

    function EnableNextButton() {

        var button = jQuery(".StartNextButton")
        var checkBox = jQuery(".AcceptedAgreement input:checkbox");

        if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
            button.removeAttr("disabled");
            $('.InsertRow').show();
        
       
        }
        else {
            button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

    }



    $('#Wizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepPreviousButton').click(function () {

        var formElements = $('#Wizard1_uxSimilarSuggestion1').find('#lblTotalCharacter').text();
     
        alert(formElements);
        $('input#uxInsertTitle').val('k');
        $("#uxInsertTitle").val("kd");

    

    });

</script>
</html>
```

worked.

Comment: i add alert to code,when click StepPreviousButton in step two the code not fount the textbox and change value it.why not found?

Comment: Without including you html code, it will be hard for us to point out where the error is

Comment: Please provide complete snippet with HTML and jquery code

Comment: as far as stack allow me to post ...i post html my code files

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID of elements not the as.net encoded id of those elements.
Try below code.

```
$('#StepPreviousButton').click(function () {      
    $('#uxInsertTitle').val(' ');
});
```

Eg:
If there is a label like this `<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>` then use ID as `lblMsg` and not the asp.net encoded ID.

Below are some reference example to make u understand my point.
Ref: [Click HERE](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/06/jquery-html-or-asp-button-click-event.html)

GOT IT?

Comment: this problem not relate to id .you said. when click botton go to click function .also not found and not change textbox

Comment: Can you post that button and textbox elements here?